# Regex to extract pattern from string until a symbol occurs, or the string ends

Tags: r, regex, stringr

I have an issue where I want to extract a pattern from a vector of strings, ie extract
`c("TAG a", "TAG b", "TAG c")` from `c("TAG a", "TAG b-3", "TAG c+3")`

So far I've tried:

```
str_vec <- c("TAG a", "TAG b-3", "TAG c+2", "2+TAG d")

stringr::str_extract(str_vec, "TAG .*(?=[\\+\\-])")
```

Which returns TAG b and c correctly, but doesn't extract TAG a or d.

If I try

```
stringr::str_extract(str_vec, "TAG .*(?=[\\+\\-]|$)")
```

TAG a and d are returned correclty, but `$` seems to override +/- so TAG b and c are returned with their suffixes still attached.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need

```r
str_vec <- c("TAG a", "TAG b-3", "TAG c+2", "2+TAG d")
stringr::str_extract(str_vec, "TAG [^+-]*")
# => [1] "TAG a" "TAG b" "TAG c" "TAG d"
```

*Details*:

- `TAG`  - a fixed string
- `[^+-]*` - zero or more chars other than `-` and `+`.

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/leqTBR/1) and the [R demo](https://ideone.com/CWPOP8).

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```r
library(stringr)

str_extract(str_vec, "TAG [a-z]")
```

Output:

```r
[1] "TAG a" "TAG b" "TAG c" "TAG d"
```

Comment: my bad, I should have made it clearer, the pattern within is more complex than in the example...
However maybe just matching everything but +/- will solve it